# java.util.Sublist throwing StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, error-handling, stack-overflow

We are getting occasional StackOverFlowError errors in production related to doing a SubList operation. Has anyone seen something like this before and know what could cause it?

This is the code that gets called that triggers the error:

```
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String newViewID = context.getViewRoot().getViewId();

    if (newViewID != null) {
     if (breadCrumbs.contains(newViewID)) {
      // Trims the list upon going back to allow for multiple back button requests.  
      // This is lightweight and not intended for a complex circular navigation.
      breadCrumbs = breadCrumbs.subList(0, breadCrumbs.indexOf(newViewID) + 1);
     } else {
      breadCrumbs.add(newViewID);
     }
    }
```

The result :

```
Caused By: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.SubList$1.<init>(AbstractList.java:688)
 at java.util.SubList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:687)
 at java.util.SubList$1.<init>(AbstractList.java:688)
 at java.util.SubList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:687)
 ...
```

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using ? SubList from open JDK doesn't seem to have this infinite loop problem : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java#SubList

Comment: There's the reason why below (sublist of mutable list), but what it looks like you want to do is remove the trailing elements from the crumb list and not create a new view of the old list with them hidden (what sublist does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by breadCrumbs being a LinkedList-- we were adding too many items to the LinkedList and calling subList exposed this problem.

Answer (score 6):

The subList() method returns a view *backed by the original list*.

According to the javadoc:

> The semantics of the list returned by
>   this method become undefined if the
>   backing list (i.e., this list) is
>   structurally modified in any way other
>   than via the returned list.
>   (Structural modifications are those
>   that change the size of this list, or
>   otherwise perturb it in such a fashion
>   that iterations in progress may yield
>   incorrect results.)

You are making structural changes to the list, so all bets are off -- *anything* can happen, including infinite recursion, which is what appears to be happening.

Comment: In other words, you should do this instead: `breadCrumbs = new ArrayList(breadCrumbs.subList(0, breadCrumbs.indexOf(newViewID) + 1));`

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem using both LinkedList standard library and [fastutil objectarraylist](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/ObjectArrayList.html) (fastutil are a fast and efficient memory implementation of Java collection framework).

Using

```
window = window.subList(index+1, window.size());
```

caused stackoverflow error. I replaced with

```
window = new LinkedList<>( window.subList(index+1, window.size()) );
```

and everything worked fine.

Hopes it can help

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extract of the relevant source:

```
681    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(final int index) {
...
687        return new ListIterator<E>() {
688            private ListIterator<E> i = l.listIterator(index+offset);
```

This `StackOverflowError` indicates that `l` is somehow referring to the **current** sublist and is thus calling its own `listIterator()` in an infinite loop.

Where does the `breadCrumbs` come from? What does its `getClass()` say?

Comment: @Colin: you missed the `$1` part?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is because of LinkedList. I have got the same error while calling subList against the same list recursively. I think that each time the method subList is called, its begin/end indices are pushed in stack. If that list is huge and therefore too many times that method is called, StackOverFlowError occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way AbstractList.java (base class of ArrayList) implements the subList method. It creates the sublist (aka view) by means of a parent pointer, an offset and a size.
If you call subList on such a subList you get parent pointer pointing to the list which itself has a parent pointer (etc.)

Some operations (e.g. add) on sublists work recursivly. If you have a very deep hierarchy of parent pointers you get a StackOverflowError.

The following snippet shows the problem isolated:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    lst.add(""); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        lst.set(0, "test");
        lst = lst.subList(0, 1);
    }

    lst.add("test2");       
}
```

Conclusion: Do not use subList recursively like this:

```
breadCrumbs = breadCrumbs.subList(0, breadCrumbs.indexOf(newViewID) + 1);
```

Instead set the length by removing elements from the end.

More detailled analysis on my blog: http://programmingtipsandtraps.blogspot.com/2013/05/javautillistsublist-stackoverflowerror.html

Comment: we're not using subList recursively or calling a "subList on ... a subList"